# Как подменить функцию в google test

Tags: c++

- У меня есть функция `testable`, которую я тестирую.
- Внутри используется функция `foo`, которую мне нужно как-то подменить.

--

```
int foo(int a){
  if (a > 0)
    return 42;
  else
    return 13;
}

int testable(int a){
  return foo(a) * 2;
}
```

В тесте мне нужно протестировать функцию `testable`, но мне нужно, чтобы внутри использовалась другая функция вместо `foo`.

```
TEST(Test, Test1){
  // Тут я хочу, чтобы функция 'testable' использовала 
  // не настоящую 'foo', а некую подмену.

  // foo(1)  -> 10;
  // foo(12) -> 120;
  // foo(-3) -> -30;
  // иначе   -> 0;

  EXPECT_EQ(testable(1), 20);
  EXPECT_EQ(testable(12), 240);
  EXPECT_EQ(testable(-3), -60);
  EXPECT_EQ(testable(666), 0);
}
```

Можно это как-то организовать?

Comment: `#define foo bar`?

Comment: передавайте нужные функции указателем. `typedef int funt(int); int testable(funt * f ,int a){return f(a) * 2;} int fun0(int){..} funt arrayfun[10]={fun0,fun1,...}; for(..arrayfun..) testable(fi,234);...`